# Математические операции с двоичными числами

Tags: числа

Как можно сложить, вычесть, умножить,разделить два двоичных числа (11001,01 и 10101,111101) в форме с плавающей запятой?

Comment: опишите, что вы делали и с какими проблемами столкнулись.

Comment: Все действия делаются так же, как и в десятичной системе.

Comment: Я бы посчитал на калкуляторе.

Comment: Господин **@Egor** хотел бы уточнить: Конкретнее опишите вопрос. Где вы хотите это сделать? С помощью каких средств? Одно дело, выполнить это на бумаге, а другое, в программе.

Comment: На бумаге,не в программе

Answer (score 2):

`11001.01` (в двоичной системе) = `25.25` (в десятичной системе)
`10101.111101` (в двоичной системе) = `21.953125` (в десятичной системе)

Сложение: `25.25 + 21.953125 = 47.203125 = 101111.001101`

Вычитание: `25.25 - 21.953125 = 3.296875 = 11.010011`

Умножение: `25.25 * 21.953125 = 554.31640625 = 1000101010.01010001`

Деление: `25.25 / 21.953125 = 1.1501779359431 = 1.00100110`

Comment: Я думаю, автор вопроса хотел бы увидеть подробное описание того, как вы это делали

Comment: @Andrei Khotko без проблем

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, элементарно же: `$ echo 'obase=2; ibase=2; 11001.01+10101.111101; 11001.01-10101.111101; 11001.01*10101.111101; 11001.01/10101.111101' | bc`

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich с меня +1 :)